# How to track the opening of a hamburger menu and assign a value to a variable when the menu opens?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `hamburger menu`, I need to change the value of the `NavigationHelper.pagePosition` variable when opening the `hamburger menu`. When opening the menu from different screens, you need to assign different values to this variable. I just tried to set a value when clicking on the button to open the `menu`, but I got an error. Tell me how to track the opening of the `hamburger menu` and when opening (both by clicking and swiping) assign a value to the variable I need?

**main**

```
child: Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        appBar: LogoAppBar(
            buttonIcon: SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.burgerMenu),
            onPressed: () {
              Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
              NavigationHelper.pagePosition = PageEnum.poyntDashboard;
              print(NavigationHelper.pagePosition);
            }),
        endDrawer: const HamburgerMenu(),
```

**appBar** with hamburger icon

```
class LogoAppBar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
  const LogoAppBar({
    Key? key,
    this.buttonIcon,
    this.onPressed,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final SvgPicture? buttonIcon;
  final Function()? onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return SafeArea(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: horizontalPadding),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                if (buttonIcon != null)
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: onPressed,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      child: buttonIcon,
                    ),
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `context` you are passing to `Scaffold.of` does not have the `Scaffold`'s inherited widget. As you can see, this `context` that you pass comes from your `build` method arguments, or some other widget builder **above** your `Scaffold`. You can get your hands on a `BuildContext` containing your `Scaffold` though. You may do it in two ways:

- Use `Builder` widget under the `Scaffold`. This widget simply gives you a callback with a fresh `BuildContext` containing all of the inherited widgets above this `Builder`.

  Here's [Flutter Widget of the Week on `Builder`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXNOkIuSYuA).
- Pass `GlobalKey` to your `Scaffold` and use its state for invoking the `openEndDrawer` method. Simply instantiate a `GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>` in your widget (ideally, as a property of a stateful widget to avoid unnecessary re-instantiating during consecutive builds. Then, pass this key as your `Scaffold`'s `key` parameter. Then, in your `onPressed` callback, instead of retrieving `ScaffoldState` using `Scaffold.of()`, access it with `scaffoldKey.currentState`